# ImportError on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I tried to run my Python script on Windows machine, but I get this error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\telegram\main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
  File "C:\Users\Balcony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from .jobqueue import JobQueue, Job
  File "C:\Users\Balcony\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telegram\ext\jobqueue.py", line 26, in <module>
    import pytz
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'"
```

My Code:

```
import logging
import requests
import re
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
from telegram.ext import KeyboardButton


# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# Define a few command handlers. These usually take the two arguments update and
# context. Error handlers also receive the raised TelegramError object in error.
def start(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Hi!')


def help(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /help is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text(f'Help! 1234')


def echo(update, context):
    """Echo the user message."""
    update.message.reply_text(f'Вы написали:   {update.message.text}')
    print(update.message.text)
```

Of course, I installed all packages.

And the same py file is working correctly on MacOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from telegram.ext import Updater

add `.ext`

Comment: this is completely different error, as i see you are missing `pytz` module please try install the module with `pip install pytz` and run it again if you still geting similar errors just try pip install it.

Comment: Yes, finally it works! asked for couple more modules and  ¡voalá!